# JBoss Fuse and Fuse ESB, whats the difference?

Tags: fuseesb, jbossfuse

It seems that Fuse ESB has been bought out by Red Hat and will now be provided as *JBoss Fuse*.

Is it correct to presume they are essentially the same technology, plus or minus a few improvements?

I see that both are open source and built on the same technology stack, so I am hopeful that this is just a name change without any significant impact to existing projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes its a name change as part of the acquisition. JBoss Fuse is the new name the product is using now, from its new owner Red Hat.

There will be no new releases of the old product (Fuse ESB) from FuseSource.

Comment: If I need older version of FUSE ESB, what am I supposed to do. I need FUSE ESB 7.1

Comment: You can download Fuse ESB 7.1 from Red Hat customer portal

Comment: https://www.jboss.org/products/fuse.html this is link I am redirecting to. Is there any other page available for fuse ESB. :(

Comment: I know its free, but I couldn't find any link. :(.

Comment: Here is fully free open source upstream project of fabric feature of RedHat JBoss Fuse, http://fabric8.io/